# Python 3.5 int() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'x', 'a', and 'b'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I've not been coding long, only 3 months. One of the questions set in my Python class was to create a script that will find the root of a function using Newtons method, I initially wrote the code without the user defining the initial guess, and it worked exactly how I wanted it too. However when I change the guess so that a user can pass through their own guess, I got a bizarre error that I've never seen before.

**Heres my code:**

```
def f(x):
    return 1 + x + 1/(x + 3)**3;

def fprime(x):
    return 1 - 3/(3 + x)**4;

guess = int(input("Enter an initial guess: ")) # Convert to an int immediately.
for i in range(1,10):
    nextGuess = guess - f(guess)/fprime(guess)
    print(nextGuess)
    guess = nextGuess
```

**Complete error message**

> ---> guess = int(input("Enter an initial guess: ")) # Convert to an int immediately.
>        56 for val in range(1,10):
>        57     nextGuess = guess - f(guess)/fprime(guess)
>
> TypeError: int() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'x', 'a',
>   and 'b'

Comment: You defined a function called `int` somewhere with four parameters, is my guess. Shadowing the built-in function.

Comment: @Mitch
I have a bunch of integration code in the same jupyter notebook(not in the same cell), could that be where my problem is coming from?

Comment: Did you name a function `int`?

Comment: @mitch
I didn't have any function named int(), but I put the code into its own notebook, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: thanks for your help man!

Comment: Can I ask what your imports were in that notebook?